How to fix: iPhone users are not receiving my SMS messages
A few days ago my Pixel 6 phone (on Verizon through Xfinity mobile) stopped sending messages to iphone users.
Symptom:
Send and receive to another android phon.
Messages sent to 2 different iphones arrive there, but I do not get their replies. I can call both of them and receive calls from both of them.
I'm in southwest Virginia if that helps.
I've tried:

Restart. Shut down and startup.
Disable wifi and force to use mobile network.
Updated the Google Messages app.

I've tried:

Make sure you are sending plain SMS not an RCS message. RCS is not yet supported by iOS.
